# Cloud scheduler trigger on the first monday of each month

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a job to trigger on the first Monday of each month:

This is the cron expression I got: `0 5 1-7 * 1`
(which ,as far as I can read unix cron expressions, triggers at 5:00 am on Monday if it happens to be in the first 7 days of the month)

However the job is triggered on what seems to be random days at 5:00 am. the job was triggered today on the 16 of Aug!

Am I reading the expression awfully wrong? BTW, I'm setting the timezone to be on AEST, if that makes difference.

Comment: Check out the [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month) on superuser.com

Comment: You can check [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_5_1-7_*_1) what your cron expression really means.

Comment: @jabbson , well that's an interesting behavior. Sadly GCP will not let me input anything but a cron expression. It's time to wrap the scheduler in the logic instead.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I used crontab guru to come up with the expression, but apparently there is a caveat in the situation I'm describing. Check Jabbson comment if you're interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the legacy [cron syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#cron_yaml_The_schedule_format) to describe the schedule.

For your case, specify something like below:
"first monday of month 05:00"

Do explore the "Custom interval" tab in the provided link, to get better understanding on this.